# Create an array of buttons from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create a bunch of buttons in the html body based on an array stored in Javascript. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
     <head>
           <script>
                var listBrand =['LEXUS','AUDI','MAYBACK','FERRARI','TOYOTA'];   
                //the array
                function printBtn() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < listBrand.length; i++) {
                       var btn = document.createElement("button");
                       var t = document.createTextNode(listBrand[i]);
                       btn.appendChild(t);
                       document.body.appendChild(btn);
                    }
                }
           </script>  
     </head>
     <body>
          <div onload="printBtn();">
          
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

I want to have all 5 buttons `LEXUS`, `AUDI`, `MAYBACK`, `FERRARI`, and `TOYOTA` show up in the body when the page loads, but the buttons fail to appear.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Any help and/or explanations are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is okay, use `<body onload="printBtn();">` and you are good to go

Comment: ah, I understand now. Because the "document.body.appendChild(btn)" only apply for the <body>, not the <div> itself. If I want to call within the div, i must give it an id="divBtn" then "document.divBtn.appendChild(btn)"

Comment: No, the problem is about using `onload` on `div`, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onload` event can only be used on the `document/body`, `frames`, `images`, and `scripts`.

It can be attached to only body and/or each external resource. The `div` is not an external resource, so the `onload` event doesn't apply there.

Use following:

```
<body onload="printBtn();">
```

Instead of

```
<div onload="printBtn();">
```

And you are good to go.

Maybe you should take a look at [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588040/3367974) here on SO too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the `div` element doesn't have an `onload` event.

You should bind the `printBtn` method to the `window.onload` event instead.

I created a working jsfiddle for you to see :
https://jsfiddle.net/5rq60y0u/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would just move your script to the end of the body, and then you don't need to worry about `onload` at all. If you have images and things like that, `onload` won't fire until after they all load. No reason to wait for that.

Also your `doctype` is wrong, and the `head` is missing the required `title` tag. It's a good idea to validate your HTML code with the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
          <title>Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
           <script>
                var listBrand =['LEXUS','AUDI','MAYBACK','FERRARI','TOYOTA'];

                function printBtn() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < listBrand.length; i++) {
                       var btn = document.createElement("button");
                       var t = document.createTextNode(listBrand[i]);
                       btn.appendChild(t);
                       document.body.appendChild(btn);
                    }
                }
                
                printBtn();
           </script>  
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So for example if I want to show those buttons in a specified div, I can still put it within that div ?

Comment: Sure, just get a reference to the div with any of the usual functions such as `var yourdiv = document.getElementById()`, and then instead of using `document.body.appendChild()` use `yourdiv.appendChild()`.

Comment: And one more thing is, each buttons have class=".." onclick="..." value="..." inside, how can I add them at the line "createElement" ?

Comment: `btn.className = "...";`, `btn.value="..."`, etc. For the event handler consider using `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`, although you can do it that way too. You may also want to consider using jQuery for this to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is one error in your code !

You cannot use the onload() function in div tag because div is not an external resource and it's loaded as part of the body, so the onload event doesn't apply there . You can use the onload() function in body tag .

Try the below code , it work perfectly !

```js
var listBrand =['LEXUS','AUDI','MAYBACK','FERRARI','TOYOTA'];   
                //the array
                function printBtn() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < listBrand.length; i++) {
                       var btn = document.createElement("button");
                       var t = document.createTextNode(listBrand[i]);
                       btn.appendChild(t);
                       document.body.appendChild(btn);
                    }
                }
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
    Created By Muhammad Usman
           <script>
                
           </script>  
     </head>
     <body onload="printBtn();">
          <div>

          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```